# Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined when using module.export

Tags: javascript, html, module.exports

**Complete error:** Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at vsop87Bearth.js:1

I`m trying to use some js files that I found from this(https://github.com/commenthol/astronomia) repository to calculate the rectangular coordinates of the sun. I'm new to js and servers so im not sure on how to use module.exports.
There is a file called *vsop87Bearth.js* with some coordinates that modelates the earth and it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  stuff: numbers,
  name: "earth"
};
```

And I need to use the *vsop87Bearth.js* file with a function called *position()* to do what I need. This is the module *Funcion_PSol.js* where Im trying to calculate things:

```
import position from './astronomia-master/src/solarxyz.js'
import Planet from './astronomia-master/src/planetposition.js'
import * as earth from './astronomia-master/data/vsop87Bearth.js' //I'm not sure of THIS line
var tierra = new Planet(earth);
var pos = position(earth, 2448908.5)
```

Also, the error might be caused from the HTML file, this is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module" src="./astronomia-master/data/vsop87Bearth.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Funcion_PSol.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Note: I´m using browsersync to host my project and Im  not using Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the esm syntax, you will need to update the export syntax to the following.

```js
export = {
  stuff: numbers,
  name: "earth"
};
```

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_json_modules

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is this:

```
const earthData = require('astronomia/data/vsop87Bearth')
```

That will import the data you want into the `vsop87Bearth` variable. That variable will then have the properties you want, like `earthData.L` or `earthData.name`.

Their README file has more example: https://github.com/commenthol/astronomia#using-a-single-package

---

Just a feedback, when you "import as"

```
import * as earth from './astronomia-master/data/vsop87Bearth.js'
```

You use the `earth` variable, not `data.earth` as you had.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it gets me a 'require is not defined' error

Comment: Did you create a proper Javascript project? Did you install the astronomia dependency? Maybe you could update your question to post your project structure as well...